# Cómo organizar en Visual Net un proyecto bajo el modelo MVC?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

Para comenzar desde cero un proyecto en Visual Net bajo el modelo MVC se separa el código de gestión de la base de datos y el de la lógica cada uno en una clase independiente o en un módulo independiente?

Es decir:
Modelo - todo lo que sea gestión de la base de datos (1 clase o módulo)

Vista - los formularios con su diseño gráfico (los formularios y diálogos que sean necesarios, en algunos casos llamada a código del Controlador)

Controlador - la lógica del programa (1 clase o módulo)

Answer (score 1):

yo cuando realice un proyecto con code-first efectivamente se separa en módulos. en la carpeta Views para organizar las diferentes páginas para Insertar, Editar, Eliminar y Consultar.

En cambio en los modelos y las controladoras se separa únicamente por clase, que yo recuerde Visual es muy amigable y fácil respecto a eso únicamente creas tu modelo y automáticamente te crea la controladora y el modulo en view con sus diferentes páginas.

Unicamente si necesitas algo más especifico modificas en tu controladora y la página correspondiente.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @diegoAlbertoZarateLara yo estoy usando Visual Studio Community 2015 pero no encuentro la opción para crear un proyecto basado en MVC. Tengo que instalar algo especial? Alguna plantilla nueva? Si voy a las plantillas disponibles para Visual Basic no aparece ninguna para MVC.
Si veo algunas para MVC pero para trabajo con C# o Angular

Comment: Hola de nuevo, que yo recuerde viene incluido con la instalación de visual studio 2015 en la selección de nuevo proyecto debe aparecer la opción de ASP.NET Web Application das en ok y visual te desplegará las opciones en donde podrás seleccionar el tipo de proyecto incluyendo MVC. En la parte de abajo aparecerán unos checkbox indicando que incluir debe estar seleccionado MVC para que incluya lo necesario carpetas y archivos .dll para realizar proyectos MVC

Comment: Muchas gracias @diegoAlbertoZarateLara yo lo buscaba en Visual Basic, ahí el problema